# I want a cross close button on top of my overlay.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an overlay which appears over my webpage. I want a cross symbol on top of my overlay so that users can closs the overlay. So How i can close the overlay if the user presses escape key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {  
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
//close the overlay
}
```

[**`jquery keyup`**](http://jsfiddle.net/yJTJz/5/)

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yJTJz/3/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it..

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
   if (e.which == 27){
     $('#closeButtonId').trigger('click');
   }
});
```

assuming that your *cross* button has a click handler attached that closes the overlay..

```
$('#closeButtonId').click(function(){
   $('#overlay').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      if (e.keyCode ==27){
            $('#your x-button').click();
    }
```

Comment: Please tell what your answer is about too.